# Read Only root for Archlinux ARM

Tags: readonly, root-filesystem

I am running Archlinux ARM on Raspberry Pi 3 model B. I want to use the Pi for running my mother's favourite news channel on YouTube with Firefox's kiosk mode.

My mother will  be the Pi's user, but she doesn't know how to use a PC or laptop so she can't shut it down after watching her favourite news channel. So she'll rather toggle the power button to turn the raspberry pi on or off. That's why I have planned to use read-only file system to prevent data corruption.

---

Currently I am running lxdm and xfce4 (autologin), but if I specify the `/` to mount as `ro` in the `/etc/fstab`, after a reboot, lxdm shows the login screen, but I can't start xfce4 session. I have also tried fluxbox which also has the same behaviour as xfce4.

I have tried mounting /var/ as tmpfs, /home/ as tmpfs, but none of them successfully let me login to the graphical user interface. I have also exported XAUTHORITY to /tmp, which doesn't help as well.

How can I mount the `/` partition as read only?

Comment: You should consider overlayfs, like Live distributions are doing.  The difficult part is to boot with / on overlayfs and also to have a way to still do upgrades (sort of "maintenance mode", without overlayfs)

Comment: Can't she just turn off the monitor? A Pi 3 does not use much power.

Comment: Hi, @A.B, I don't need any maintenance, she just needs YouTube (and probably Gradio sometimes) and nothing else, so there's not need to worry about security, she doesn't need any of the new features, so better keep her system as it is!!

Comment: @MichaelHarvey she can leave it running, but power outage is a very very common thing here, 10 - 12 outages a day aren't very uncommon here, and can't use power banks because the power has to be disconnected in order to charge the power bank, hence the idea of mounting / as read only...

Comment: You can get a case with a power button that shuts the Pi down or starts it when pressed, the [Pi Desktop](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14354)

Comment: The maintenance wasn't about security (even if that would be a good reason), it's about further customizing the installation. "Mother> but I told you I wanted to have it start with that other channel by default not the one I get when I push power."